# Validating Recaptcha 2 (No CAPTCHA reCAPTCHA) in ASP.NET's server side

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, recaptcha

[The new Recaptcha 2](http://googleonlinesecurity.blogspot.com/2014/12/are-you-robot-introducing-no-captcha.html) looks promising, but i didn't find a way to validate it in ASP.NET's server side,

`if(Page.IsValid)` in [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5817690/validating-recaptcha-on-server-side), is valid for the old Recaptcha, but not the new one,

How to validate the new reCAPTCHA in server side?

Comment: Don't they have rest endpoints to validate

Comment: Try this. You have to post user response to google ans based on response, proceed. More here. https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify

Comment: @saravanan, You're right, the solution should be here, i will try to code it.

Comment: Try this [**Install-Package reCAPTCH.MVC**](https://www.nuget.org/packages/reCAPTCH.MVC/)

Answer (score 157, accepted):

After reading many resources, I ended up with writing this class to handle the validation of [the new ReCaptcha](http://googleonlinesecurity.blogspot.com/2014/12/are-you-robot-introducing-no-captcha.html) :

As mentioned [Here](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify) : When a reCAPTCHA is solved by end user, a new field (g-recaptcha-response) will be populated in HTML.

We need to read this value and pass it to the class below to validate it:

In C#:

In the code behind of your page :

```
string EncodedResponse = Request.Form["g-Recaptcha-Response"];
bool IsCaptchaValid = (ReCaptchaClass.Validate(EncodedResponse) == "true" ? true : false);

if (IsCaptchaValid) {
    //Valid Request
}
```

The Class:

```
  using Newtonsoft.Json;

    public class ReCaptchaClass
    {
        public static string Validate(string EncodedResponse)
        {
            var client = new System.Net.WebClient();

            string PrivateKey = "6LcH-v8SerfgAPlLLffghrITSL9xM7XLrz8aeory";

            var GoogleReply = client.DownloadString(string.Format("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret={0}&response={1}", PrivateKey, EncodedResponse));

            var captchaResponse = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ReCaptchaClass>(GoogleReply);

            return captchaResponse.Success.ToLower();
        }

        [JsonProperty("success")]
        public string Success
        {
            get { return m_Success; }
            set { m_Success = value; }
        }

        private string m_Success;
        [JsonProperty("error-codes")]
        public List<string> ErrorCodes
        {
            get { return m_ErrorCodes; }
            set { m_ErrorCodes = value; }
        }


        private List<string> m_ErrorCodes;
    }
```

In VB.NET:

In the code behind of your page :

```
Dim EncodedResponse As String = Request.Form("g-Recaptcha-Response")
    Dim IsCaptchaValid As Boolean = IIf(ReCaptchaClass.Validate(EncodedResponse) = "True", True, False)

    If IsCaptchaValid Then
        'Valid Request
    End If
```

The Class:

```
Imports Newtonsoft.Json


Public Class ReCaptchaClass
    Public Shared Function Validate(ByVal EncodedResponse As String) As String
        Dim client = New System.Net.WebClient()

        Dim PrivateKey As String = "6dsfH-v8SerfgAPlLLffghrITSL9xM7XLrz8aeory"

        Dim GoogleReply = client.DownloadString(String.Format("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret={0}&response={1}", PrivateKey, EncodedResponse))

        Dim captchaResponse = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of ReCaptchaClass)(GoogleReply)

        Return captchaResponse.Success
    End Function

    <JsonProperty("success")> _
    Public Property Success() As String
        Get
            Return m_Success
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_Success = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_Success As String

    <JsonProperty("error-codes")> _
    Public Property ErrorCodes() As List(Of String)
        Get
            Return m_ErrorCodes
        End Get
        Set(value As List(Of String))
            m_ErrorCodes = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private m_ErrorCodes As List(Of String)

End Class
```

Comment: And if users don't want to import `Newtonsoft.Json` and create a whole defined Json object, they could just use `JavaScriptSerializer` from `System.Web.Script.Serialization` and deserialise to a plain 'ol object, like shown [in this stackexchange answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20079177/deserializing-json-in-visual-basic/20080495#20080495)

Comment: Your answer was really helpful Ala.  This is what I did to remove the dependency on Newtonsoft:          

JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        MyObject data = js.Deserialize<MyObject>(GoogleReply);

        var captchaResponse = data.success;

        return captchaResponse.ToString();
    }

    public class MyObject
    {
        public string success { get; set; }
    }

Comment: Thank you Ala. A side note, in the code, bool IsCaptchaValid = (ReCaptchaClass.Validate(EncodedResponse) == "True" ? true : false);, you don't need the ? true : false, it's redundant.

Comment: I used this one it always returning false why like that?

Comment: this: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/851004/How-to-Validate-Recaptcha-V-Server-side is the best solution I found.

Comment: Seems like a bit excessive when you are ignoring the error messages that are being returned. Might be better to refactor into a real class that can be instantiated, checked for validation and be able to get the error message(s) when it doesn't pass validation. Otherwise, Paul's more streamlined solution below seems to be the better solution.

Comment: btw I would not share private key here. Make a new one for your app

Comment: Just to say, the result from the Validate function is true with small t and hence I was pulling my hair out why it was not working.

Comment: this does not work if already a client-side validation, cause the response is successful only once, not twice, so if already validated by the client side, the server second validation will return false... @VijayKumbhoje

Comment: is there a way to make this work without using the HttpContext.Current.Request.Form ??

Comment: Love this answer, it's perfect for my needs!

Answer (score 44):

Here's a version that uses the JavaScriptSerializer. Thanks Ala for the basis for this code.

**WebConfig App Setting** - 
I've added the secret key to the Web.Config in my case to allow transforms between environments. It can also be easily encrypted here if required.

```
<add key="Google.ReCaptcha.Secret" value="123456789012345678901234567890" />
```

**The ReCaptcha Class** - A simple class to post the response parameter along with your secret to Google and validate it. The response is deserialized using the .Net JavaScriptSerializer class and from that true or false returned.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;

public class ReCaptcha
{   
    public bool Success { get; set; }
    public List<string> ErrorCodes { get; set; }

    public static bool Validate(string encodedResponse)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(encodedResponse)) return false;

        var client = new System.Net.WebClient();
        var secret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Google.ReCaptcha.Secret"];

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(secret)) return false;

        var googleReply = client.DownloadString(string.Format("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret={0}&response={1}", secret, encodedResponse));

        var serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();

        var reCaptcha = serializer.Deserialize<ReCaptcha>(googleReply);

        return reCaptcha.Success;
    }
}
```

**Validate The Response** - Check the validity of the g-Recaptcha-Response form parameter in your Controller (or code behind for a web form) and take appropriate action.

```
var encodedResponse = Request.Form["g-Recaptcha-Response"];
var isCaptchaValid = ReCaptcha.Validate(encodedResponse);

if (!isCaptchaValid)
{
    // E.g. Return to view or set an error message to visible
}
```

Comment: This seems to be a good solution for those interested in the simplest implementation, especially without using the Newtonsoft libraries.

Comment: I went with this solution. Simple, good explanation, and easy to follow.

Comment: this does not work if already a client-side validation, cause the response is successful only once, not twice, so if already validated by the client side, the server second validation will return false...

Answer (score 21):

Most of these answers seem more complex than needed. They also dont specify the IP which will help prevent a interception attack (https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/81865/is-there-any-reason-to-include-the-remote-ip-when-using-recaptcha). Here's what I settled on

```
public bool CheckCaptcha(string captchaResponse, string ipAddress)
{
    using (var client = new WebClient())
    {
        var response = client.DownloadString($"https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret={ ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Google.ReCaptcha.Secret"] }&response={ captchaResponse }&remoteIp={ ipAddress }");
        return (bool)JObject.Parse(response)["success"];
    }
}
```

Comment: Excellent solution. Simple and effective.

Comment: Thanks from 7 years in the future!

Comment: @markau its nice that old stuff i wrote is still helpful 

Answer (score 6):

You can use "IsValidCaptcha()" method to validate your google recaptcha on server side. Replace your secret key with "YourRecaptchaSecretkey" in the following method.

```
Public bool IsValidCaptcha()
 {
  string resp = Request["g-recaptcha-response"];
  var req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create
            (https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=+ YourRecaptchaSecretkey + "&response=" + resp);
     using (WebResponse wResponse = req.GetResponse()) 
       {
       using (StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader(wResponse.GetResponseStream()))
         {
          string jsonResponse = readStream.ReadToEnd();
          JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
          // Deserialize Json
          CaptchaResult data = js.Deserialize<CaptchaResult>(jsonResponse); 
            if (Convert.ToBoolean(data.success))
              {
               return true;
              }
         }
      }
     return false;
 }
```

Also create following class as well.

```
public class CaptchaResult
  {
   public string success { get; set; }
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

According to the [doc](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify) you just post your secret key and user's answer to API and read returned "success" property

SHORT ANSWER:

```
        var webClient = new WebClient();
        string verification = webClient.DownloadString(string.Format("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret={0}&response={1}", secretKey, userResponse));
        if (JObject.Parse(verification)["success"].Value<bool>())
        {
            // SUCCESS!!!
```

FULL EXAMPLE:

Suppose, you implement [this](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display) page in **IamNotARobotLogin.cshtml**.

```
<head>
 <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="Login" method="POST">
  <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="your_site_key"></div><br/>
  <input type="submit" value="Log In">
</form>
</body>
```

And suppose you wish the controller saved, let's say, "I_AM_NOT_ROBOT" flag in the session if the verification succeeded:

```
    public ActionResult IamNotARobotLogin()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Login()
    {
        const string secretKey = "6LcH-v8SerfgAPlLLffghrITSL9xM7XLrz8aeory";
        string userResponse = Request.Form["g-Recaptcha-Response"];

        var webClient = new System.Net.WebClient();
        string verification = webClient.DownloadString(string.Format("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret={0}&response={1}", secretKey, userResponse));

        var verificationJson = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(verification);
        if (verificationJson["success"].Value<bool>())
        {
            Session["I_AM_NOT_A_ROBOT"] = "true";
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Demo");
        }

        // try again:
        return RedirectToAction("IamNotARobotLogin");
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's my fork of Ala's solution in order to:

- send paramter in POST
- to sanitize the form input
- include the requester IP address
- store the secret in Web.Config:

In the controller:

```
bool isCaptchaValid = await ReCaptchaClass.Validate(this.Request);
if (!isCaptchaValid)
{       
    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid captcha");
    return View(model);
}
```

The utility class:

```
public class ReCaptchaClass
{
    private static ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
    private static string SecretKey = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Google.ReCaptcha.Secret"];
    [JsonProperty("success")]
    public bool Success { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("error-codes")]
    public List<string> ErrorCodes { get; set; }

    public static async Task<bool> Validate(HttpRequestBase Request)
    {
        string encodedResponse = Request.Form["g-Recaptcha-Response"];          
        string remoteIp = Request.UserHostAddress;          
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            var values = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
               {"secret", SecretKey},
               {"remoteIp", remoteIp},
               {"response", encodedResponse}
            };
            var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);
            var response = await client.PostAsync("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify", content);
            var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var captchaResponse = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ReCaptchaClass>(responseString);
            if ((captchaResponse.ErrorCodes?.Count ?? 0) != 0)
            {
                log.Warn("ReCaptcha errors: " + string.Join("\n", captchaResponse.ErrorCodes));
            }
            return captchaResponse.Success;
        }
    }       
}
```

Answer (score 3):

[This article](https://dejanstojanovic.net/aspnet/2018/may/using-google-recaptcha-v2-in-aspnet-core-web-application/) give clear step by step explication on how to implement a ReCaptcha validation attribute on your model.

First, create the Recaptcha validation attribute.

```
namespace Sample.Validation
{
    public class GoogleReCaptchaValidationAttribute : ValidationAttribute
    {
        protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
            Lazy<ValidationResult> errorResult = new Lazy<ValidationResult>(() => new ValidationResult("Google reCAPTCHA validation failed", new String[] { validationContext.MemberName }));

            if (value == null || String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace( value.ToString())) 
            {
                return errorResult.Value;
            }

            IConfiguration configuration = (IConfiguration)validationContext.GetService(typeof(IConfiguration));
            String reCaptchResponse = value.ToString();
            String reCaptchaSecret = configuration.GetValue<String>("GoogleReCaptcha:SecretKey");

            HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
            var httpResponse = httpClient.GetAsync($"https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret={reCaptchaSecret}&response={reCaptchResponse}").Result;
            if (httpResponse.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                return errorResult.Value;
            }

            String jsonResponse = httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            dynamic jsonData = JObject.Parse(jsonResponse);
            if (jsonData.success != true.ToString().ToLower())
            {
                return errorResult.Value;
            }

            return ValidationResult.Success;
        }
    }
}
```

Then add the validation attribute on your model.

```
namespace Sample.Models
{
    public class XModel
    {
        // ...
        [Required]  
        [GoogleReCaptchaValidation]  
        public String GoogleReCaptchaResponse { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Finally, you have just to call the ModelState.IsValid method

```
namespace Sample.Api.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    public class XController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Post(XModel model)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

Et voilà ! :)

Comment: Perfect. Also, add "using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration" in the attribute class. IntelliSense didn't make it obvious for me.

Answer (score 1):

Another example is posted here:

[RecaptchaV2.NET (Github)](https://github.com/xantari/RecaptchaV2.NET)

It also implements the secure token option of Recaptcha 2.0 (look at full source code for that bit, I have stripped out relevant pieces of code ONLY for validating a result).

This one doesn't rely on newtonsoft's json parser and instead uses the built in .NET one.

Here is the relevant snippet of code from the RecaptchaV2.NET library (from recaptcha.cs):

```
namespace RecaptchaV2.NET
{
  /// <summary>
  /// Helper Methods for the Google Recaptcha V2 Library
  /// </summary>
  public class Recaptcha
  {

    public string SiteKey { get; set; }
    public string SecretKey { get; set; }
    public Guid SessionId { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Validates a Recaptcha V2 response.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="recaptchaResponse">g-recaptcha-response form response variable (HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["g-recaptcha-response"])</param>
    /// <returns>RecaptchaValidationResult</returns>
    public RecaptchaValidationResult Validate(string recaptchaResponse)
    {
      RecaptchaValidationResult result = new RecaptchaValidationResult();

      HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=" + SecretKey + "&response="
        + recaptchaResponse + "&remoteip=" + GetClientIp());
      //Google recaptcha Response
      using (WebResponse wResponse = req.GetResponse())
      {
        using (StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader(wResponse.GetResponseStream()))
        {
          string jsonResponse = readStream.ReadToEnd();

          JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
          result = js.Deserialize<RecaptchaValidationResult>(jsonResponse.Replace("error-codes", "ErrorMessages").Replace("success", "Succeeded"));// Deserialize Json
        }
      }

      return result;
    }

    private string GetClientIp()
    {
      // Look for a proxy address first
      String _ip = HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];

      // If there is no proxy, get the standard remote address
      if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_ip) || _ip.ToLower() == "unknown")
        _ip = HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];

      return _ip;
    }
  }

  public class RecaptchaValidationResult
  {
    public RecaptchaValidationResult()
    {
      ErrorMessages = new List<string>();
      Succeeded = false;
    }

    public List<string> ErrorMessages { get; set; }
    public bool Succeeded { get; set; }

    public string GetErrorMessagesString()
    {
      return string.Join("<br/>", ErrorMessages.ToArray());
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: what does the extra HttpWebRequest URL parameter, "remoteip", do?  We're not using the "remoteip" paremeter, and are having intermittent issues with receiving the Request Response.  The response is null when the issue happens.

Answer (score 1):

Google's ReCaptcha API no longer accepts the payload as query string parameters in a GET request.  Google always returned a "false" success response unless I sent the data via HTTP POST.  Here is an update to Ala's (excellent!) class which POSTs the payload to the Google service endpoint:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;

public class RecaptchaHandler
{
    public static string Validate(string EncodedResponse, string RemoteIP)
    {
        var client = new WebClient();

        string PrivateKey = "PRIVATE KEY";

        WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify");
        string postData = String.Format("secret={0}&response={1}&remoteip={2}",
                                         PrivateKey,
                                         EncodedResponse,
                                         RemoteIP);

        byte[] send = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(postData);
        req.Method = "POST";
        req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        req.ContentLength = send.Length;

        Stream sout = req.GetRequestStream();
        sout.Write(send, 0, send.Length);
        sout.Flush();
        sout.Close();

        WebResponse res = req.GetResponse();
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(res.GetResponseStream());
        string returnvalue = sr.ReadToEnd();

        var captchaResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RecaptchaHandler>(returnvalue);

        return captchaResponse.Success;
    }

    [JsonProperty("success")]
    public string Success
    {
        get { return m_Success; }
        set { m_Success = value; }
    }

    private string m_Success;
    [JsonProperty("error-codes")]
    public List<string> ErrorCodes
    {
        get { return m_ErrorCodes; }
        set { m_ErrorCodes = value; }
    }

    private List<string> m_ErrorCodes;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using dynamic to validate recaptcha at server side

Calling Function

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ClientOrderDetail(FormCollection collection, string EncodedResponse)
{
    Boolean Validation = myFunction.ValidateRecaptcha(EncodedResponse);

    return View();
}
```

Function Declaration

```
public static Boolean ValidateRecaptcha(string EncodedResponse)
{
    string PrivateKey = "YourSiteKey";

    var client = new System.Net.WebClient();

    var GoogleReply = client.DownloadString(string.Format("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret={0}&response={1}", PrivateKey, EncodedResponse));

    var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    dynamic data = serializer.Deserialize(GoogleReply, typeof(object));

    Boolean Status = data["success"];
    string challenge_ts = data["challenge_ts"];
    string hostname = data["hostname"];

    return Status;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the example I posted in [this so post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4611122/how-to-implement-recaptcha-for-asp-net-mvc#41631278) uses Newtonsoft.JSON to deserialize the full returned JSON, posts the data  to Google(as opposed to using a querystring) stores the relevant variables in the web.config rather than hard coded.